How much flexibility do I have when a delay has caused me to miss my connection (UK national rail)?
Suppose I have bought an advance single ticket for a UK rail journey that requires a change of trains at some intermediate point. By default, my ticket is valid only on a specific pair of trains. However, if the first train is delayed such that I miss the connection, I am entitled to take a later service for the second leg.
Am I then obliged to take the first available train that is travelling to the appropriate destination? Or can I choose to spend additional time at the intermediate station? (For example, it might now be more convenient to stop and get dinner at the intermediate station rather than waiting until I reach the final destination; or perhaps it's just rush-hour and I'd prefer to wait for a quieter train). How much flexibility do I have?

In Germany the answer would be "yes". If you missed the connection you can take any train in any sequence as long as they are going in the right direction.

@Hilmar: And on the other hand, in France, you'd have to ask the company to offer an alternative, and would typically only have a handful of alternatives to pick from.

@Hilmar that is true, but they still recommend to get a confirmation at a station's helpdesk to avoid trouble with conductors. Also, you are not allowed to switch from DB to Flix.

It turns out LNER has a policy on this:

Use your original ticket to travel on another service


If your train is cancelled, you can use your existing ticket to travel on either of the two services before or after your cancelled service, along with any required connections at the start or end of your journey. These services must meet the route and operator conditions of your ticket.


You do not need to change your ticket or buy a new one to travel.


This is an industry-wide agreement, so includes non-LNER journeys and connections. If an alternative service is not available, please speak to a member of railway staff.

So it seems like +/- 2 trains applies to other companies.  GWR, Thameslink, SWR say the same.  I couldn't find any obvious mention on the help pages of Avanti, Scotrail, TPE or Chiltern, but I didn't look super hard.

I read "either of the two services before or after" as +/- 1, not +/- 2.

Thameslink writes it as "You can use your ticket on the previous two, or the next two available services to your destination." ie +/- 2 not +/- 1.

±2 makes a lot of sense in practice as it spreads the extra passengers out over more services than ±1 train (@TypeIA). One I was on recently, with seats booked, was the next after a cancelled train.  They were practically begging people to wait for the next one again, but these were every half hour and it would have screwed up our connections for the rest of the day so we sat on our bags in the aisle - even if we could have got to our booked seats they'd turned off the reservation system

National Rail Conditions of Travel:


What Happens When Things Go Wrong?



28.1 We want you to be satisfied with your journey. If you have any problem that cannot
be resolved to your satisfaction at the time, every Train Company provides details of
how to make a complaint or comment on its website and on notices at stations and
on trains.


28.2 Where disruption prevents you from completing the journey for which your Ticket is
valid and is being used, any Train Company will, where it reasonably can, provide
you with alternative means of travel to your destination, or if necessary, provide
overnight accommodation for you.


28.3 Where your train is likely to be delayed for more than 60 minutes, you may use your
Ticket to make your journey at a later date subject to comparable restrictions on your
Ticket. Please refer to your Train Company’s website or contact them directly for
details on how to obtain a replacement Ticket.


28.4 In other circumstances disruption to train services may mean that you are entitled to
compensation or a refund on your Ticket. Part F explains your rights to refunds and
compensation.


28.5 If your train is delayed for more than 60 minutes, your Train Company may, in certain
circumstances, provide you with meals and refreshments if they are available on the train
or in the station, or can reasonably be supplied, and in reasonable relation to the waiting
time.

In practice, when there is major disruption ticket restrictions may be lifted which allow you to travel on any train, or operators will announce they are accepting tickets from another operator.  If they aren't explicitly lifted, you can ask staff if you are allowed to travel on another operator, especially if there are no suitable alternatives from the original operator.

However, if OP voluntarily takes a much later train and has additional delays that cause them to miss the final connection to their final destination, I can imagine the TOC might pushback against overnight accommodation or a late-night long taxi ride.

So are you saying that if I miss my 9am connection I can choose to wait until the last train of the day at 10pm?

@gerrit obviously, the (possibly unwritten) rule is to take the most expeditious route and time schedule possible. So for a trip from Bristol to Aberdeen via Birmingham, with the service interrupted between Birmingham and Manchester, making side trips to London and Liverpool isn't covered unless without those Aberdeen could not be reached.

@avid If it were to come before a judge they would apply a 'reasonableness' test. eg if your direct train was cancelled and there wasn't another for 8 hours, maybe you could argue it's reasonable to wait for that, especially if you couldn't manage changing for some reason like disability. But if there was another direct train in 10 minutes then it wouldn't be reasonable to wait for hours. If caught, you'd be arguing (by letter etc) with their Revenue Protection people, who are quite used to people looking for loopholes and you may not win that fight.

@user1908704 But that's exactly the focus of my question...


, I am entitled to take a later service for the second leg.

Only if on the same operator. If there are no later trains from your operator, then your original operator has the obligation to reroute you and you be carried with another operator

? (For example, it might now be more convenient to stop and get dinner at the intermediate station

A Advance ticket has no break of journey allowed, meaning you won't be able to leave the platforms at barriered stations.

But note (with respect to the last paragraph) that even if you're not delayed, barrier staff will almost invariably let you out and back in when waiting at an interchange station.  I see this nearly every day. Given that basic facilities like toilets are quite commonly only available outside the gate line they can't really refuse, or not reasonably.  And if there are barriers, there are staff (they lock them open if there aren't enough staff).

"Break of journey" means leaving the station, not leaving the platforms. In many stations you have to pass through a barrier to access one part of the station from another. It is also not BoJ to transit between two station sites with a recognised interchange.

Arguably, "break of journey" means not taking the intended connection.  With a 45 minute changeover, taking a walk or two around the block is not a break of journey?

@gerrit BoJ has a defined technical meaning as described, in particular on some semi-flexible tickets which are not tied to specific trains. In practice stepping outside for fresh air or to get some food from outside the station is fine and permitted by staff, even if no BoJ is allowed. But stretching this (say going to a football match during a connection)  is more likely to get you into trouble if discovered when BoJ is actually banned on your ticket.
